# Overwritten Block appears in addition to Module Overwrite

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Magento 1.4.1.1

Back in history, **app/code/core/Mage/GoogleAnalytics/Block/Ga.php** was copied over to **app/code/local/Mage/GoogleAnalytics/Block/Ga.php** and changes were made so the `protected function _toHtml() {}` function would produce a proper Google Analytics asynchronous javascript entry on the page. The original had issues that didn't post tracking information to Google properly for this website. This rewrite was fully functional with the desired result.

In order to clean things up, it was decided to modularize this change to a local namespace module. The following files were created...

apps/etc/modules/Chief_GoogleAnalytics.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Chief_GoogleAnalytics>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Chief_GoogleAnalytics>
    </modules>
</config>
```

apps/code/local/Chief/GoogleAnalytics/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Chief_GoogleAnalytics>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Chief_GoogleAnalytics>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <googleanalytics>
                <rewrite>
                    <ga>Chief_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga</ga>
                </rewrite>
            </googleanalytics>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Chief/GoogleAnalytics/Block/Ga.php

```
/**
 * GoogleAnalitics Page Block
 *
 * @category   Chief
 * @package    Chief_GoogleAnalytics
 * @author     Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Chief_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga extends Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga
{
    /**
     * Prepare and return block's html output
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('google/analytics/active')) {
            return '';
        }

        $this->addText('
<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(["_setAccount", "' . $this->getAccount() . '"]);
    _gaq.push(["_trackPageview", "'.$this->getPageName().'"]);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement(\'script\'); ga.type = \'text/javascript\'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = (\'https:\' == document.location.protocol ? \'https://ssl\' : \'http://www\') + \'.google-analytics.com/ga.js\';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName(\'script\')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
//]]>
</script>
<!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
        ');

        $this->addText($this->getQuoteOrdersHtml());

        if ($this->getGoogleCheckout()) {
            $protocol = Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure() ? 'https' : 'http';
            $this->addText('<script src="'.$protocol.'://checkout.google.com/files/digital/ga_post.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
        }

        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```

Instead of the single corrected script entry as was normal when it was coming from **app/code/local/Mage/GoogleAnalytics/Block/Ga.php**, I now get a duplication. The Chief_GoogleAnalytics Block overwrite comes first, followed by the old stock junk code from **app/code/core/Mage/GoogleAnalytics/Block/Ga.php**. There is a single layout XML file for Google Analytics that defines it to show in **after_body_start**, so that's working. Here's the duplication where the new Block overwrite and old Block are showing. What gives?

```
<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(["_setAccount", "UA-xxxxxx-x"]);
    _gaq.push(["_trackPageview", "/"]);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
//]]>
</script>
<!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->

<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);
    })();

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(["_setAccount", "UA-xxxxxx-x"]);
    _gaq.push(["_trackPageview", "/"]);
//]]>
</script>
<!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
```

page.phtml entries that load the block.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
```

googleanalytics.xml layout

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <!-- Mage_GoogleAnalytics -->
        <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="googleanalytics/ga" name="google_analytics" as="google_analytics" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**Added forensics by use of** `Mage::Log()` **with** `$this->getData()` **in strategic locations**
Since we're passing an array object around here, it's a little more complicated than working with a string.

**Start of _toHtml() function**

```
2012-06-24T21:02:04+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [type] => googleanalytics/ga
    [module_name] => Chief_GoogleAnalytics
)
```

**Immediately cause it to load** `parent::_toHtml();` **with** `$original_output =parent::_toHtml`

```
2012-06-24T21:02:04+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [type] => googleanalytics/ga
    [module_name] => Chief_GoogleAnalytics
    [account] => UA-xxxxxx-x
    [page_name] => /
    [text] => 
<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);
    })();

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(["_setAccount", "UA-xxxxxx-x"]);
    _gaq.push(["_trackPageview", "/"]);
//]]>
</script>
<!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->

)
```

To prevent this from turning into a ;tldr, logging `$this->getData();` where the return was at the end, spits out both javascripts, but in reverse of the original.

`$this->getData();` without ever referencing `parent::_toHtml` passes the following which is what we want for a returned object. One script with proper identifiers...

```
2012-06-24T21:06:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [type] => googleanalytics/ga
    [module_name] => Chief_GoogleAnalytics
    [account] => UA-xxxxxx-x
    [page_name] => /aircraft
    [text] => 
<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(["_setAccount", "UA-xxxxxx-x"]);
    _gaq.push(["_trackPageview", "/aircraft"]);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
//]]>
</script>
<!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->

)
```

Comment: Bonus points for specifying the specific version number, as this would not have been as easy to solve without it.

Comment: Thanks, I find it helps quite a bit. Nothing like answering a question over on MagentoCommerce to find they're on 1.2.x.x and so your answer's irrelevant. ;^)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, a seemingly-but-not-really-pedantic naming convention.  When you put files in `local` that's not a rewrite, it's a code pool override.  When you create a custom module and use the `rewrite` node, that's a class rewrite.  These are **two** different actions, and each one behaves differently.  These differences are why you're seeing the behavior you're seeing.

When you use a class override, you're saying

> Hey Magento, instead of including your class file for a `Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga`, include mine instead

This completely replaces the original class in the system.

When you use a class rewrite, you're saying

> Hey Magento, **when you instantiate** a `googleanalytics/ga` (`Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga`) block object, instantiate the object from my class instead.

Then you, by having your class extend the original `Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga` class have an object that behaves the same as the original object, and you can add your methods.  However, when you add your methods their parent method is the **original** block, which is different from an override.

Step one would be removing the local code pool file

```
app/code/local/Mage/GoogleAnalytics/Block/Ga.php
```

It sounds like you've already done this. Next, there's the method in your rewritten class.  When you call the `parent::_toHtml();` method

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    //... your stuff here ...
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

you're telling Magento "Hey, do whatever the original object would have done".  With blocks and the `_toHtml` method, that means producing the same output.  That's why you're getting the "old stock junk code".  The contract for the `_toHtml` method is "whatever string this returns, will be included as the block output".  Your new code is also being included because you're using the `addText` method, which your parent method is aware of.

So, if you want to change the behavior of `_toHtml` in a block rewrite, you need to do something like this

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $original_output = parent::_toHtml();
    $string = '';
    //... your code here which ultimately generates your output
    //and places it in $string
    return $string;
}
```

By calling the parent method first, you ensure that anything the block does from a state point of view still happens (which a block shouldn't do, but, well, we know how that goes).  Then, you return your string instead.

Comment: Don't reference `parent::_toHtml()` in the function and `return $this->getData('text');` seems to be doing it. Thank you for reiterating the difference between the module override and rewrite. I fully understand what's going on now. I'd need to do additional testing through the cart to make sure it was logging sales order information as well, as I'm not calling it like explained, but as indicated in my answer to Ben Marks, I've carried it to its current logical conclusion for the education as the new version I'm upgrading to has been updated to make the module unnecessary. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**DDx:** does commenting out the `<block type="googleanalytics/ga" ... />` code from `googleanalytics.xml` cause all output to disappear?

*Assuming the local codePool override file has been removed*, the issue certainly is `return parent::_toHtml()`. The CE 1.4.1.1 version of the parent (core) method uses `addText()` which is derived from `Mage_Core_Block_Text->_toHtml()`. `addText()` will append content to `_data['text']`, and then the  method will return this in course of rendering. So, your override is setting some string content to `_data['text']`, and then when you call the parent method, it adds *its* content to `_data['text']` and then calls `Mage_Core_Block_Text->_toHtml()`, which simply returns the value of `_data['text']`.

Generally it's a good idea to call the overridden method, but this is a case where it's not going to work. Given that this method was changed in 1.4.2.0 to just return the string from a local variable, you should be fine to ignore the parent. If this doesn't work out for some bizarre reason it would be possible to use layout XML to replace the core block instance with another.

Comment: Yes, commenting the line in the layout removes both blocks. And app/code/local/Mage/GoogleApps/Block/Ga.php was removed previous to installing the Chief_GoogleAnalytics module. In the recommendation to ignore the parent, do you mean comment it out? `// return parent::_toHtml(); `

Comment: Yep. You will need to return the text from your metod though, so you should duplicate the logic from [`Mage_Core_Block_Text`](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text.php)`->_toHtml()`

Comment: I had a look at the differences in code between 1.4.1.1 and 1.4.2.0 and it's definitely gone through a major code rewrite. The Google Analytics code is inserted as the first item after the body tag where it needs to be on the later versions. Since the exercise is a cleanup before upgrading to 1.6.2.0+ the reason for this module existing ceases to exist and any polishing of GA function be done for the target version. At least I know the modularization itself was working. Thanks for the help!